# PayPal smart payment buttons - request quantity

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm using the PayPal smart payment buttons to sell a single item on my website, but I can't find in any of the documentation how to ask for quantity.

Is this even possible to do with the smart payment buttons API?

I just want to offer the customer the ability to change the quantity of the item they wish to buy. I don't mind if it's in the form or during the checkout stage within PayPal.

Here's my code so far, it's pretty standard as I'm trying to keep it simple:

```
<script>
    // Render the PayPal button into #paypal-button-container
    paypal.Buttons({
        style: {
            size: 'responsive',
            shape: 'pill',
            label: 'checkout',
        },
        // Set up the transaction
        createOrder: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.order.create({
                purchase_units: [{
                    amount: {
                        value: '8.99'
                    }
                }]
            });
        },

        // Finalize the transaction
        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
                // Show a success message to the buyer
                alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!');
            });
        }


    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have done this but without breaking out the bill.
I made the final price "amount" as the price multiplied by the quantity and in my database I am saving all the details of the bill.
This is my javascript code I used:

```
 amount: {
         value: "<?= $_SESSION['price'] * $_SESSION['quantity'] ?>" ,
         currency_code: 'EUR'
 },
```

You can use Javascript instead of server code like this,

```
amount: {
         value: document.getElementById("quantity").value * document.getElementById("price").value ,
         currency_code: 'EUR'
 },
```

In both codes, values should be set before rendering the buttons, which means before loading the page.

Answer (score 1):

To implement quantity field on your client. you have to breakdown the amount field and then add "item_total" and "items" field in the purchase units.

for your reference:

```
createOrder: function(data, actions) {
     console.log(data);
       console.log(actions);
     return actions.order.create({
       purchase_units: [{

         amount: {
           value: (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("number1")).value,
         breakdown: {
           item_total:{
             "currency_code": "EUR",
                 value: (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("number1")).value,
               },
               tax_total: {
                 "currency_code": "EUR",
                 "value": "00.00"
               },
         }  
         },

           items: [
             {
               "name": "",
               "description": ".......",
               "sku": "sku01",
               "unit_amount": {
                 "currency_code": "EUR",
                 "value": "20.00"
               },
               "quantity": (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("number")).value,

             }]

       }],
```